# How can I use a public variable outside a method in two different class files?

Tags: java, selenium, variables

I have 2 Class files. Class_login.java and Class_Company.java.
I have an xpath stored in different location in a properties file.
A method is written in Class_login.java to load this properties file.

```
static Properties objprop1 = new Properties();
public static FileInputStream fileInputS = null;

static void propManager() throws IOException {
        fileInputS = new FileInputStream("C:\\Test-Automation\\FinanceSys\\myproj\\src\\test\\resources\\xpath.properties");
        objprop1.load(fileInputS);
}
```

`objprop1` is declared outside the method in `Class_login.java`.
I need to load this file again in `Class_Company.java`. If I use it like `Class_login.PropertyManager();` and use same objprop1 the file does not load and the xpaths are not found.
Hence I created same method with a different name(`static void PropertyManager() {`) and 
 `public static Properties objprop = new Properties();`
 I know this is not the correct way. But how can this be done otherwise?
In the main method of `Class_Company.java` I called these methods separately so that I do not get a null xpath error as earlier.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Class_login LogFeature = new Login();
    Class_Company CC = new CCompany();
    **Class_Company.PropertyManager();**
    LogFeature.OpenBrowser("CH32");
    LogFeature.EnterURL("http://localhost:90/AppFin");
    LogFeature.PageMaximise();
    LogFeature.EnterUserName("uname");
    LogFeature.EnterPassword("abcd!@");
    LogFeature.ClickLoginButton();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    **Class_Company.propManager();**
    CC.clickNewCompany("Manage");
```

Please tell me the right way of doing it. I want to use objprop in both the class files and only once in Class_Company.java. and not twice as highlighted above.

Comment: you are describing your code faaar too much, show your actual code, remove the unnecessary information and state clearly what statement is causing you problems. Furthermore please follow naming conventions of methods: `propertyManager()` instead of `PropertyManager()`.

Comment: (1) You're not closing a file that you opened. (2) Your field is static and your method is static - this is probably wrong. (3) Why do you need to call the method again if the properties are already loaded? (4) All method names should start with a lowercase letter. (5) fileInputS should probably be a local variable rather than a field or a static field.

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic example, which you need:

**Global Variable declaration:**

```
Class variableCollection {
public static string data;
}
```

**You can use this variables by extending class Or object references.**

```
class login extends variableCollection{


}
```

**OR**

```
class login{
variableCollection objvar = new variableCollection();

objvar.data = "";

}
```

You can use this same variable in multiple classes, same way.